# Changing enumerate style

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

[image]

Hello, I want to modify the design of my numbered lists from the boring 1., 2., to this, where I could have either a coloured square or circle around the number. How can I go about this?
I am using the following code right now:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
   \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
```

However, this only gives the generic bullets, 1., 2., 3. with white backgrounds.

Comment: As said before: always include a test file in your questions!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me how I can edit the text and the circle colours?

Comment: @grumpyeconomist If you have a new question, please ask a new question including a **compilable** test document